# Flask: в шаблоне не отображается модель

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Не могу понять почему шаблон не видит модель. Никаких ошибок нет.

```
@app.route('/datacenter/<int:id>')
def datacenter(id):
    datacenter = Datacener.query.filter_by(id=id)   
    return render_template('datacenter.html', datacenter=datacenter)
```

**html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>{{ datacenter.name }}</h1>
    <p>{{ datacenter.number }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.place }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.capacity }}</p>
    <p>{{ datacenter.tier }}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Если перед `return` вставить `print(datacenter)` что в консоль будет выведено?

Comment: `127.0.0.1 - - [31/May/2018 18:51:03] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
SELECT datacener.id AS datacener_id, datacener.number AS datacener_number, datacener.name AS datacener_name, datacener.place AS datacener_place, datacener.capacity AS datacener_capacity, datacener.tier AS datacener_tier 
FROM datacener 
WHERE datacener.id = %(id_1)s
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
datacenter = Datacener.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
```

а лучше так

```
datacenter = Datacener.query.get(id)
```

Comment: Точно, все заработало. Спасибо!